# Prove if $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$, then $f$ is bounded on every closed subinterval of $(a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove :

> $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R} $ is convex, then $f$ is bounded on every closed subinterval of $(a,b)$

where $f$ is convex if $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda)f(y), \forall x,y \in (a,b), \forall \lambda \in [0,1]$

---

### Try

#### $f$ is bounded above

Let $J = [\alpha, \beta] \subset (a,b)$.

$\forall c \in [\alpha, \beta]$, $\exists \lambda_0 \in [0,1]$ s.t. $c = \lambda_0 \alpha + (1-\lambda_0) \beta$, and

$$
f(c) = f(\lambda_0 \alpha + (1-\lambda_0) \beta) \le \lambda_0 f(\alpha) + (1-\lambda_0) f(\beta)
$$

thus, $f$ is bounded above on $[\alpha, \beta]$

But I'm stuck at how I should proceed to prove that $f$ is bounded below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $\gamma$ with $\alpha<\gamma<\beta$. Let $A=(\alpha,f(\alpha))$, $B=(\beta,f(\beta))$, $C=(\gamma,f(\gamma))$ Then

- on $[\alpha,\beta]$, $f$ is below the line $AB$
- on $[\alpha,\gamma]$, $f$ is above the line $CB$
- on $[\gamma,\beta]$, $f$ is above the line $AC$

("below and "above" are meant to include "on" here)[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an analytic proof that a convex function $f:[\alpha,\beta] \to \mathbb{R}$ is bounded on the closed interval.

Take $M = \max (f(\alpha),f(\beta))$. Note that any $x \in [\alpha,\beta]$ is of the form $x = \lambda\alpha + (1-\lambda)\beta$ where $0 \leqslant \lambda \leqslant 1$.

Hence, we have for all $x \in [\alpha, \beta]$, the upper bound

$$f(x) \leqslant \lambda f(\alpha) + (1-\lambda)f(\beta) \leqslant \lambda M + (1-\lambda)M = M$$

To find a lower bound, write $x = \frac{a+b}{2} + \theta$.  Since $\frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a+b}{2} + \theta  \right) +  \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{a+b}{2} - \theta  \right) $, we have by convexity

$$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} + \theta  \right) +   \frac{1}{2}f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} - \theta  \right),$$

and

$$f(x) = f\left(\frac{a+b}{2} + \theta  \right) \geqslant 2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)- f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} - \theta  \right)$$

But from the upper bound we have $-f \left(\frac{a+b}{2} - \theta  \right) \geqslant -M$, and so we have the lower bound

$$f(x) \geqslant 2f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)-M = m$$

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to first prove that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$. Then, we know that $f$ is bounded on every closed subinterval of $(a,b)$.

A proof of this assertion can be found in Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*: this is Theorem 3.2 in the third edition. (On closer inspection, this is indeed the content of @HagenvonEitzen's answer).

Comment: I doubt,can you show the continuity of $f$ without showing it boundness?

Comment: @Tom. Maybe every proof that $f$ is continuous also shows that it is bounded somewhere along the way. Convex functions are quite nice, I don't think the two notions are very different for them.