# Convexity on $(a,b) \nRightarrow$ convexity on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I have recently started learning about convex functions and have few questions on them:

1. Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be convex on $(a,b)$. Then we know $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ but not necessarily on $[a,b]$. Do we know from this that $f$ must be convex on $[a,b]$ too?
2. If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $[a,b]$, do we know $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$?
3. If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $(a,b)$, then is $f$ necessarily bounded?

**This post has been resolved. Here are the summarized answers:**

For $1$, if we define $f(x)=e^x$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=-1$, then the secant line joining $(0,f(0))$ and $(c,f(c))$ for any $0<c\leq1$ lies below the graph of $f$ and hence implies $f$ is not convex at $x=0$. Is this correct?

For $2$, we use the same trick as above and define $f(x)=e^x$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $f(0)=10$, then the secant line joining $(0,f(0))$ and $(c,f(c))$ for any $0<c\leq1$ lies above the graph of $f$, i.e., $f$ is convex on $[0,1]$. Clearly $f$ is not continuous. Is this correct?

For $3$, take $f(x)=1/x$ for $0<x \leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$. Then $f$ is convex on $(0,1)$ but it is clearly unbounded.

Extra remarks: if $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on $[a,b]$, then is $f$ necessarily bounded. (modify this proof from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2992454/prove-if-f-is-convex-on-a-b-then-f-is-bounded-on-every-closed-subinterv))

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but you should add your attempts and your thoughts on these questions.

Comment: To understand reasons for down votes and close votes, you might review our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question),  with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is simply a statement of three questions without any context at all, such as what work you might have done, and what actual mathematical issues might have arisen during your attempts.

Comment: Make a sketch of an arbitrary convex function on the open interval $(0, 1)$. Can you imagine how to define $f(0)$ or $f(1)$ such that the extended function is *not* convex on the closed interval $[0, 1]$?

Comment: You might also take a look at our suggestion to limit yourself to [one question per post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#33671).

Comment: @LeeMosher Yeah, I should have added my thoughts and attempt in the original post. I have added them now, but I think it's too late as this post has already been flagged to be taken down.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion. I drew some graphs and have added my thoughts. Not too sure if this is rigorous or even correct.

Comment: It looks much better now.

Comment: For part 3, define $f(x) = \begin{cases} +\infty, & x = 0 \\ \frac{1}{x}, & x > 0 \end{cases}$. It is convex on $(0, \infty)$ but unbounded.

Comment: @VHarisop $f$ needs to take values in $\mathbb{R}$ and domain needs to be compact. Your example is on an unbounded domain and allowing $f$ to take values in the extended real numbers.

Comment: For question 3, are you assuming $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$, or on $[a,b]$? If it's the former, then a counterexample is just $f(x) = 1/x$ for $x>0$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @Sambo I think that settles 3 too. If $f$ is convex on $[a,b]$, then it is necessarily bounded on $[a,b]$. However, if $f$ is convex on $(a,b)$ then $f$ need not be bounded. Take $f(x)=1/x $ for $0<x\leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$ Then $f$ is convex on $(0,1)$ but unbounded. But doesn't this contradicts the proof I gave that any such $f$ is bounded above by $\max \{f(a),f(b)\}$?

Comment: Your proof of 3 is wrong because you use convexity on the closed interval.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, I just realized too. I was going to edit the post to reflect this.

Comment: Note that $f$ can be unbounded above (as you now correctly demonstrated with an example), but $f$ is always bounded below.

Comment: You're allowed to answer your own questions here, so instead of editing the question to include the answer (which leaves the question incorrectly marked unanswered), you should write the answers in an Answer down below (and give credit to the commenters that helped you find them).